# Failed to open console on IBM DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

After creating my DB2 instance, I tried to open the SQL database management console but I would get this message instead:

> {"trace":"b3017f8c5e3e3407c220f5852fed4e04","errors":[{"code":"authentication_failure","message":"HWCSEC0016E:
> Authentication failed for SSO. This may caused by failed to generate
> access token in console side using existing
> credentials.","target":{"type":"","name":""},"more_info":""}]}

Please any ideas on this?

Comment: Not sure why you tagged SQL Server for a DB2 question?

Comment: Is this Db2 lite and us-south? Does the database connection work without the console?

Comment: Yes its DB2 lite but London. and the database connection does not work without a console.